# UINavigationController with UISegmentedControl in AppDelegate to switch rootviewcontroller of UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I would like to create an app with a navigation controller as a window root view controller and a segmented control in a title view of the navigation controller to switch its root view controller

Problem: segmented control is not present after adding it to nag controller

Code:

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{  
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    FirstViewController * fc = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController * nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fc];
    [fc release];

    self.window.rootViewController = nc;

    NSArray * array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"GPS",@"List",@"Map", nil];

    UISegmentedControl * sc = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:array];

    sc.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 50);
    sc.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;

    [nc.navigationItem setTitleView:sc];

    [sc release];
    [nc release];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Try adding it to fc.navigationItem, then you may need to add this segmented control view to all navigation items for each view controller presented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting titleView for NavigationItem instead set Item for it.

```
NSArray * array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"GPS",@"List",@"Map", nil];

UISegmentedControl * sc = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:array];
sc.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 50);
sc.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
```

To set in title view use this line

```
[ViewController.navigationItem setTitleView:sc];
```

To set Left or Right You can not directly add Item to Navigation bar, so create BarButtonItem with your segmentControl

```
UIBarButtonItem *segmentItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:sc];
```

add it to ViewController not to NavigationController

```
[ViewController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:segmentItem];
```